# jqGrid not calculating pages on first load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid in an ASP.NET MVC webapp.  When the page first loads, the pager buttons are disabled and always show Page 1 of 1.  However, if I change the page size, sort a column or perform a search, the pages update appropriately.

I've tried triggering reloadGrid in both gridComplete and loadComplete but neither are doing the trick.  What is being called when I perform the other actions that gets the paging to refresh?

Here is my grid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#grid').jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetGridData", "MyController")',
        datatype: 'json',
        loadonce: true,
        mtype: 'POST',
        postData: {},
        colNames: ['Name', 'Price', 'Inventory'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
            { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', sorttype: 'float', formatter: 'number', align: 'right' },
            { name: 'Inv', index: 'Inv', sorttype: 'int', align: 'right' }
        ],
        pager: '#gridpager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        sortname: 'Name',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Inventory',
        hidegrid: false,
        forceFit: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 1200
        //loadComplete: function() {     
        //    $('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");
        //},
        //gridComplete: function () {
        //    $('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");
        //}
    }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: false }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', { del: false, add: false, edit: false, search: false });
```

Server code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    List<Inventory> data = InventoryModel.GetInventory();

    var count = data.Count;

    var jsonData = new
        {
            total = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / rows),
            page = 1,
            records = count,
            rows = (from row in data
                    select new
                    {
                        id = row.Name,
                        cell = new object[]
                            {
                                row.Name,
                                row.Price,
                                row.Inv                         
                            }
                    }).ToArray()
        };
    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "total":11,
  "page":1,
  "records":104,
  "rows": [ { "id":"PRODUCT-1", "cell":["PRODUCT-1",0.52,41] },
            { "id":"PRODUCT-2", "cell":["PRODUCT-2",0.43,50] },
          ... ]
}
```

Comment: If I remove loadonce: true, it shows correctly, but then I lose the client-side sorting that I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost sure that the reason is the wrong JSON data which return the server. I suppose that the server returns `total` equal to 1 independent from the `rowNum` which will be send to the server as the `rows` parameter. It's important to understand that the grid body will be have the first `rowNum` (10) rows in the same order like from the server response. Because you use `loadonce: true` then the next refreshing of grid work *locally* and so it works correct. In any way the server should fill correct `total` parameter and it should use provide the data sorted corresponds to `sortname` and `sortorder` option of jqGrid. The parameters will be sent to the server as `sidx` and `sord`.

**UPDATED**: The reason if the bug in jqGrid 4.3.1

the line

```
ts.p.lastpage = Math.min( ts.p.page, Math.ceil(len/ rn) );
```

should be fixed to

```
ts.p.lastpage = Math.ceil(len/ rn);
```

For more information see my bug report [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/typing-bug-with-maxmin-in-addjsondata-and-addxmldata/#p25471) and the fix in the version of jqGrid on github [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/78355aa4d0400cc6d07745d9235a9e99b12de2cb)

Comment: Perhaps my JSON data is not in the correct format for jqGrid?  I added my server code to the question above.  When I debug, I see the "total" value is 11 (which is correct for my data set).

Comment: @Paul: If would be good if you include the JSON response too. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for example to catch HTTP traffic. If you use ASP.NET MVC you can just define `string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows` as parameter of `GetGridData` and the method can declared as returned `JsonResult`. Moreover you use `i = row.ModuleName` which produce wrong ids as 1, 2, 3. You should use `id = row.ModuleName`. I can recommend you to read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) additionally.

Comment: Thanks.  I made some changes to my server code and added the JSON being returned, but still no luck.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry, but how you can see from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Paul.htm) the pager works without any problem with the JSON data which you posted.

Comment: I read elsewhere that using loadonce: true disables the total in the json response.  That still doesn't explain why your demo works and mine doesn't.

Comment: @Paul: I agree that `total` could not be the reason of your problem. In any way the problem is **NOT** in the code and the data which you posted. If you would post the link to the full Visual Studio project I could download and test it.

Comment: Thank you for the offer.  However, I am unable to do so in order to protect my company's IP.  I'll keep working at it and post an answer when I find one.

Comment: @Paul: Then you should debug the project and find the reason yourself. In any way my demo shows that the jqGrid can display the JSON data which you posted. I recommend you to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` for debugging, use of cause the last (4.3.1) version of jqGrid and set breakpoint somewhere in `updatepager` function which can make pager disabled (see near of `.addClass('ui-state-disabled')`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7173/discussion-between-paul-and-oleg)